# Cannot resolve symbol 'getActivity'

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to implement a fragment, and am using the [Android example](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) as a guide.

In the onActivityCreated() method of the TitlesFragment class, there is this line:

```
View detailsFrame = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.details);
```

When I try to include a similar line in my code, I get the error that the 'getActivity' symbol can't be resolved.

I've tried importing everything that their example imports, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.  Nor can I find any documentation anywhere that helps me know how to make this accessible.

So, what's the secret on being able to use getActivity?

Answer (score 0):

make sure your class extends Fragment or ListFragment, as shown in the example

```
public static class TitlesFragment extends ListFragment {
  @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
      ...
      View detailsFrame = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.details);
      ...
  }
}
```